# android-How to get json data sent by parse push notification

Tags: android, json, android-notifications

I'm using parse.com for sending push notification .it works fine .

I want to send this json data via parse.com :

```
{"channel":"game","data":{ "alert":"Red Sox win 7-0!"}}
```

this is my mainAcitivity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

    // inform the Parse Cloud that it is ready for notifications
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

}
```

1- How can I get this json data ?

2- I sent a json data , How can I disable the notification ? When application got the the json , a notification showed and said "parse push notification" . How can I disable this notification if I was sending a json data ?

Answer (score 8):

> the problem is How can I get this json in android?

You get the Json Notification Data:

```
   try {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");

        Log.v("Pares Data", jsonData);
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonData);=
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
```

Source can be found [here](https://parse.com/questions/how-do-i-get-the-json-from-a-push-notification-in-android-when-the-activity-is-opened-by-clicking-on-the-notification)

Answer (score 0):

Set the "title" json entry as it is described in [Parse's own tutorial](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android) as

> (Android, Windows 8, & Windows Phone 8 only) the value displayed in
>   the Android system tray or Windows 8 toast notification.

I.e.

```
{"channel":"game","data":{ "alert":"Red Sox win 7-0!","title":"INSERT TITLE HERE"}}
```

Comment: thanks for reply , the problem is How can I get this json in android?